# Accessing $_post value via TWIG template

Tags: php, forms, post, twig

I have a working home.php which renders the TWIG-style home.html template. home.php accesses my DB and renders the resulting DB rows in the twig template via a form. The form is a single field select list. I want to select one of the records an pass it on to a subsequent php pgm. For that I use $_post. But I can not access the posted value in the resulting php pgm. What is wrong with my code?
Sorry, I am new to twig (using it without symfony) and coding knowledge in php is just basic. Thanks for any tips!
Rendering twig template in **home.php**:

```
<?php
echo $template->render(array_merge(['mydata1' => $mydata1]),(['post' => $_POST]));
?>
```

Form in the TWIG template **home.html**. *mydata1.Title* is the DB-value that I want to post to action.php

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" name="tl1">
            <label for="mydata1.Title" style="display:inline-table;">
                <span>{% set k=1 %}
                    <select name="tl1">
                    {% if mydata1.records_count > 0 %}
                        {% for i in range(0, mydata1.records_count - 1) %}
                            <option value="{{ mydata1.Title[loop.index0] }}"> {{ mydata1.Title[loop.index0] }} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    </select>
                </span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Button Text" name="tl1" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
```

Finally echoing the posted value in **action.php**:

```
echo "The posted value from home.php is: ",$_post['mydata1.Title'];
```

What I want to do is hitting the button next to the form (named 'Button text' in the code above) I want to pass the selected list value of the form "mydata1.Title" (Title=fieldname) to  action.php and use it there.

I have tried a lot of variations both in home.php and home.html, but none of my attempts ever showed any DB value in action.php.
Form rendering works as espected. Output in action.php is an empty $_post variable.

Comment: Its `$_POST`, not `$_post`

Comment: O.K., corrected this in my code. But it did not help. echo $_POST returns still empty.

Comment: And your form field is named `tl1`, so your code should at least be `$_POST['tl1']`

Comment: Yes, I saw this too while I was correting $_POST. Didn't help either.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump` on the whole `$_POST` global array?

Comment: Now I did. Within home.php the result is `array(0) { }` and doing it within action.php it tells me "This page is not working"

Comment: Ah, I got it working now! Made my adaptations in the wrong place. Now I can move on.  Thanks for the hints!